Have a couple lego set bags but cant figure out what set it is?
Found these in a garage sale and cant seem to figure out what set its from. Theres 6 bags and the first one has little people in them.

This question is similar to: How can I identify a set based on one or more original sealed bags?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Following the process outlined here, based on the parts White Pneumatic T Piece and White Minifigure, Utensil Statuette / Trophy with NASA Astronaut Pattern, this bag can only come from 21321 International Space Station.
